# How to create Product Attributes and Attributes Set in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How to create Product Attributes and Attributes Set in magento ?
[image]

'Lift Type' is product attribute's Title

```
it has two main options Like..
    1. Manual   (Radio Button)
    2. Motorized    (Radio Button)

First Option 'Manual' has many options like (Nikal,White,Ivory).
same as 
Second Option 'Motorized' has many options like (12v Wireless,24v Quiet Motor).

When click on 'Manual' then we must choose 'Select Chain Type' 
after selection...
change the price
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please be more specific on what your question is?

If you only want some general information about creating attributes and attribute sets, like your question states, you can investigate the Magento knowledge base:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-create-an-attribute-set